# How to create a self-signed wildcard SSL certificate for IIS 6?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, wildcard, self-signed

I'm trying to create a self-signed wildcard SSL certificate for use on a number of development and test servers running IIS 6.  Following various guides has led to a couple ways of generating the certificates, but I haven't had any luck getting it to work.  The most successful ways I've had were following [this OpenSSL guide](http://beyondintegration.blogspot.com/2008/06/self-signed-certificates-how-to-get.html) and using makecert.exe like so:

```
makecert.exe -r -b 01/01/2009 -e 01/01/2042 -sr LocalMachine -ss MY -a sha1 -n CN="*.example.com" -sky exchange -pe -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -sy 12 -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" wildcard.cer
```

Both of which generate certificates that IIS 6 will accept, but when I actually try to view the site I get the following error in firefox:

> ### Data Transfer Interrupted
>
> The connection to dev.example.com was interrupted while the page was loading.

IE just gives:

> ### Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - You are not connected to the Internet.
> - The website is encountering problems.
> - There might be a typing error in the address.

This error happens whether I try to access it by domain name, machine name, localhost, local ip, or loopback ip.

So...how can I create a self-signed wildcard cert that IIS 6 will work with? Or how can I fix the problems I'm experiencing with the ones I've already created?

Comment: Possibly OT, but to generate a wild-card SSL cert a most excellent utility is `selfssl7`, available here: http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/04/16/setting-up-ssl-made-easy.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the IIS 6 Resource Kit provided by MS, an command line app called SelfSSL. It can generate the SSL key and import it into your IIS installation.

[IIS 6 Resource  Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56FC92EE-A71A-4C73-B628-ADE629C89499&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

you can do a wildcard certificate with *.domain.local and multiple ssl protocols by using the c:\inetpub\adminscripts adsutil.vbs set w3svc[siteid]\SecureBindings ":443:name.domain.local"

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize that you would need to change from "example.com" to some thing more appropriate to your situation ("localhost" might be one of them during testing).

Comment: I changed it to example.com for illustration purposes here, per [RFC 2606](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt)  
I used real domains for my implementation.  And if I hadn't, errors about non-matching domains would be expected, not data transfer interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

For IIS 7 - there is a wzard to do this.  It takes about 30 seconds to setup.

For IIS 6 - it's a bit trickier.  It takes about 30 minutes to setup.

Which one are you using?

I strongly recommend moving to IIS 7 - it is very foreign at first, but they've made a lot of improvements.

Given that you probably can't upgrade to IIS 7, I had to do the following to implement what you want in IIS 6.

1) create certificate server
2) generate request
3) grant request
4) install certificate

It's a bit of a pain to setup the certificate authority server, but it comes with Windows Server and the walkthrough is pretty straight forward.

Comment: This is for XP development machines, so Certificate Server wasn't an option either. I did do exactly those steps with the OpenSSL guide I linked to above, but even after installed it still wouldn't work, with the errors detailed. /:

Comment: Where do I find the wizard that helps creating a wildcard certificate? Whenever I use the "Create self signed certificate..." wizard, I can't choose that it should be wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that the Certificate Authority wasn't being trusted because of domain settings and was causing the errors.  We ended up deploying a star cert generated by a trusted CA and that cleared up the problems.