# Enabling SSL on cookies for live environments and non SSL on dev environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, ssl

Basically, there is a requirement in my site that means that all cookies must be secured. I am trying to secure the FormsAuthentication cookie, however, I would like it so that on my local dev site I do not have to setup SSL, however the live sites will still secure the cookie.

This live/dev status is stored in a configuration xml file. This file contains settings for each machine that the site runs on. It can be accessed via Config.IsSecure

```
if (Config.IsSecure)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, login.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, "User", FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    string cookieStr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieStr);
    cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;


    System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    AuthenticationSection authenticationSection = (AuthenticationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
    FormsAuthenticationConfiguration formsAuthentication = authenticationSection.Forms;
    formsAuthentication.RequireSSL = true;
    cookie.Secure = true;
    configuration.Save()
}

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, false);
```

So I get an error on the Save part. Saying that there is a temporary file that cannot be accessed.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Gurpreet

Comment: The simplest answer is in production secure your site with an IIS rule that will force all requests to be HTTPS, and then use config transformations to turn the `requireSSL` property of forms authentication config to be true.

Comment: hey Chris, how would I go about "use config transformations to turn the requireSSL property of forms authentication config to be true"

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, or why you've had to write custom code to do it. I believe you can configure the Forms Authentication to use SSL for cookies in web.config. Then simply have a different web.config for live and development.

The requireSSL attribute should do exactly what you want? (set the cookie to secure only, so that browsers only return the forms auth cookie when on a secure connection).

Something like (in web.config)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms  timeout="30" loginUrl="/MyLogin.aspx" protection="All" requireSSL="True" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manage two web.config files, another option would be to simply install a cert on your local machine - it's really not hard to do.

I think the answer to [How to create a self-signed wildcard SSL certificate for IIS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474609/how-to-create-a-self-signed-wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-iis-6) has the information you need.  Just make sure that you set the host name appropriately - either your machine name, or localhost, or you'll get a warning when trying to connect to your site.

It's also possible to execute transformations on web.config if you're using VS2010/.net 4, I believe:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx

Comment: I am trying to avoid the creation of certificates on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

um. you can't secure cookies without securing the whole site. cookie is exchanged using the standard HTTP request that downloads the page, so every page will have to be secure.

what you are securing is the login form... but that's not the cookie. the cookie will still be non-secure if you redirect back to http site after authentication.

**Update:**

HttpCookie.Secure only does one thing - if there's no SSL, it will not transmit the cookie to the client. The resulting cookie header will not contain your cookie if the site is accessed by HTTP. HttpCookie.Secure will not force the site to switch to SSL, it will just silently break your code, if I understand the docs correctly.

Comment: the site will be accessed via http only on development environments. The entire site runs only on SSL in the live environment

Comment: so what's the problem? enforce https-only using URL rewriter, or only allow https binding, no http. you don't need to code anything

Comment: I don't want to enforce SSL https on development machines

Comment: so don't - just change config. why are you trying to change config as part of login process?

Comment: setting cookies to secure under HTTPS and unsecure under HTTP, without human element of setting web.configs